# Add id to Google Visualization table

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Is there any way to add an ID to a Google Table Chart?  I have tried:

```
var myTable = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById(divID));
myTable.draw(data, options);
myTable.id = 'newTableId';
```

And also tried setting an id in the options:

```
var options = {
id: 'newTableId',
width: 600,
title: 'My Title',
cssClassNames: myClassNames
};
```

I didn't find any documentation to set an id and only tried those out of being hopeful.  Maybe it can't be done?  I don't want the ID of the div containing the table, but an id for the table itself which I can reference later to access data inside the table as opposed to traversing down from the containing div

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modifying CSS and finding ID of a google charts table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32057621/modifying-css-and-finding-id-of-a-google-charts-table)

Comment: I saw that and am not looking to change the CSS.  I am already using the cssClassNames option to change the CSS.  I just didn't include all the options i am setting as I did not think it pertinent to the question.

Comment: I guess this part of linked answer is relevant to your question: "If that doesn't help, you can modify the dom as needed, once the chart is `ready`. You have to specify a container id to draw the chart originally, usually a div. So you don't need the id of the google table to modify it. Just browse the contents of the container you defined using JavaScript to find what you need."

Comment: Consider using a [`ChartWrapper`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#chartwrapperobject)

Answer (score 0):

I am sure WhiteHat's answer would work as well.  For the record, I ended up doing this to set the ID as I few a few tables I am displaying:

```
//Create the table
var interestElem = document.getElementById(myID);
var table = new google.visualization.Table(interestElem);
table.draw(data, options);
//Set the ID
var thisTable = interestElem.getElementsByTagName('table');
thisTable[0].id = newTableID;
```